# My Ubuntu laptop keeps running when closing the laptop

Tags: 20.04

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 in my Lenovo Laptop.

When I simply close my laptop, without actually logging out and I put it in my backpack it keeps running all the time and my battery is almost gone and it's really warm (because of ventilator).

Is there any way I can set up the configuration so it actually hibernates? I have the feeling it keeps running some processes and not sure why

Comment: Do you want to hybernate in RAM or in HardDisk/SSD? If you hybernate In RAM then your laptop can wake up very fast, but it will need some power too. If you hybernate on Harddisk or SSD, then the power is zero, but it will take some time to wake up. But writing several Gigabyte on a SSD will damage the SSD with time. I personally shut down my Laptop every time completely.